# Is it possible to connect multiple Arduino uno boards to Raspberry pi?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, arduino

Need to connect Multiple Arduino Uno boards to Raspberry Pi for operating Appliances. After little bit of tweaking, I found some blogs for connecting single Arduino Uno board to Raspberry Pi.

Is it possible to connect multiple Arduino Uno boards to a single Raspberry Pi ?

Comment: Each arduino will have its own serial port. Something like `/dev/ttyUSB0`, `/dev/ttyUSB1`, `/dev/ttyUSB3` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a powered USB hub to connect multiple Arduno Unos to the same RPi, via USB. Use the serial connection to communicate between RPi and the Arduinos.

Do you have any special needs for the application?
If low delay is crucial, this might not be a good solution.

Comment: Its a good answer but please and try and expand a little bit more. A diagram or some code? Reference to article/s to support your answer. Thanks

Comment: There's little to draw on diagram: you just need a generic powered USB hub with enough ports and one USB cable per each Arduino. The devices will appear as /dev/ttySn where n=0,1,... - you might want to develop some solution for numbering them - if they are powered up at the same time, they will get numbers in pretty much random order.

Comment: As SF noted, there really isn't much to put on a diagram - you just connect the Arduinos via USB to the Raspberry Pi. If you need to use more than two USB ports, you should use a powered hub, in order to provide enough power.

Can you provide more insight into what your project is about? Right now, examples with code doesn't make much sense, since there is no specific goal to move towards - other than connecting of course.

Comment: As i am new to this i have some basic questions - for supplying power to each Arduino boards, should i supply power separatly for each one or is there any other alternative.can you provide me some useful links for connecting raspberry pi with Arduino and establish communication between them.

Comment: The Arduinos can be powered via USB - the easiest is to use a powered hub to ensure all Arduinos can be supplied with 500mA (since each usb port on the RPi would only provide 500mA).

Can you explain the application in detail? It might be a better solution to power the Arduinos directly (if you need 12v in your applications, you can use VIN on the Arduino to supply power, while powering the Arduinos from the onboard voltage regulator)